# Can i create new Web Application with Copy of existing Web Application Content database in Same SharePoint Farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, content-database

1.I have one web application 'WebAppA.company1.com' in production SP Farm with a content database Wss_Content_DB1 and i taken backup and restored in staging as Wss_Content_DB2 and mounted to webapplication in staging.

2.In staging i modified the design,created new page layouts,master pages and created some sub sites

3.In Staging i taken backup of Content database 'Wss_Content_DB2' and restored in same Production SharePoint Farm SQL Instance as new content database Wss_Content_DB3_FromStaging'

4. and now i want to create a new  Web Application with different host name 'WebApp2.Company1.com' in Same SP Production farm with 'Wss_Content_DB3_FromStaging' Content database

Can i do this step 4 successfully because WebApp2.company1.com content database is copy of Webapp1.company1.com database?

Answer (score 0):

We can attach an existing content database to a web application.

To attach an existing content database to a web application:

1.Restore a backup copy of the database in SQL.

2.Use the following PowerShell to attach an existing content database to a web application:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName
```

Refer to the article about attach or detach content databases in SharePoint 2013:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582.aspx